# How do I import data into a table with composite key in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, csv, import, key, composite

So I have a table with a composite key defined as follows:

```
create table BOOK_REVIEW
(
    ISBN    varchar(13)    NOT NULL,
    ID_Num  int            NOT NULL,
    Rating  int            NOT NULL,
    Review  varchar(8000),
    primary key (ISBN, ID_Num),
    foreign key (ISBN) references BOOK(ISBN)
        ON DELETE cascade  ON UPDATE cascade,
    foreign key (ID_Num) references CONTACT(ID_Num)
        ON DELETE cascade  ON UPDATE cascade
);
```

The problem I'm having is that when I import data from a properly formatted csv file, I get the duplicate entry error.  It's true that there are duplicate entries for ISBN, and there are duplicate entries for ID_Num in this table, but the composite key of (ISBN, ID_Num) is unique to each row.  Why then am I getting the error?

I can obviously omit the primary key declaration and everything will import just fine, but I need the primary key to be defined correctly.

I've tried importing to a table without the primary key definition, then moving all data to a temp table, dropping the table and recreating with the primary key constraint, then trying to move everything back...but as expected the "duplicate entry" error pops again.

Any idea how to populate a table with a composite key by importing directly from a properly formatted csv file?

Comment: For composite primary keys, SQLite checks only the combination of all the key's values. Please show some example records where you get the error but that you think should not be duplicates.

Comment: Here's some sample data in a pipe delimited csv file: [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3PtNC9AhEd2dVROdVlTcmJZblE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Google Docs doesn't like my browser. Put the two records into the question.